# May a compute shader write the same value, from many threads, to the same shared memory?

Tags: glsl, compute-shader

I would like to simulate a boolean reduction in a compute shader through the use of one `bool` variable (not an array), by simply initializing the variable with a `false` value that all threads may see, and then having each thread either contribute a `true` value to the reduction by writing it to the variable, or contribute a `false` value by doing nothing.

An example:

```
shared bool someNumberIsBig;

// ...

void main()
{
    uint id = gl_LocalInvocationID.x;
    uint gid = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;

    if (id == 0) someNumberIsBig = false;
    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();

    uint oneNumber = someBuffer[gid];

    if (oneNumber > 5) someNumberIsBig = true; // WOW that's big
    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();

    if (someNumberIsBig)
    {
        // do some work, with dynamic uniformity even, and with an
        // assurance that at least one number was indeed big...  or not??
    }
}
```

It seems straightforward to me, but maybe the competing writes to the same location could cause a problem somehow.  Am I relying on any undefined or implementation-specific behavior here?

(Another way to do what I want to do would be to write all the bools to a shared array and then run an explicit reduction algorithm on the array.  My intuition naively tells me that that would be slower than the above, but maybe it wouldn't really...  anyway, though, I'm just asking here whether the above is even correct, regardless of its efficiency.)

Answer (score 1):

Shared memory is always expensive. You can see pretty good explanation why from [false sharing](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206) article.

But if you still want to use shared memory it is supported. Only problem with them is incoherent memory and execution order. But your example solves both with memory barrier and execution barrier. If you want to do more complex operations with shared memory then you have to use atomic builtin functions. More details can be found from [OGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader#Shared_memory_coherency).